# Calling menu items from API

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, menu, menuitem

I am an Android Developer and I need that my menu item list, it's icons, it's text everything I can update by calling API I don't need to change my code again and again for that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask a question here

Answer (score 0):

you should create your custom drawer menu using recycle view and than your api call in this recycle adapter file and also create model and store your data in this model and than access this model in adapter file so you can use api in drawer menu

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.